# Python Seaborn JointGrid IndexError

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to draw a scatter plot with histograms of each dimension (above and to the right, using Seaborn's JointGrid function).

A very basic example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
sns.jointplot(x, y, color='r')
```

However, I get the following IndexError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-42ac8946b390> in <module>()
      1 x = np.random.rand(100)
      2 y = np.random.rand(100)
----> 3 sns.jointplot(x, y, color='r')
      4 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.pyc in jointplot(x, y, data, kind, stat_func, color, size, ratio, space, dropna, xlim, ylim, joint_kws, marginal_kws, annot_kws, **kwargs)
    796     grid = JointGrid(x, y, data, dropna=dropna,
    797                      size=size, ratio=ratio, space=space,
--> 798                      xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
    799 
    800     # Plot the data using the grid

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.pyc in __init__(self, x, y, data, size, ratio, space, dropna, xlim, ylim)
   1640         # Turn off the ticks on the density axis for the marginal plots
   1641         plt.setp(ax_marg_x.yaxis.get_majorticklines(), visible=False)
-> 1642         plt.setp(ax_marg_x.yaxis.get_minorticklines(), visible=False)
   1643         plt.setp(ax_marg_y.xaxis.get_majorticklines(), visible=False)
   1644         plt.setp(ax_marg_y.xaxis.get_minorticklines(), visible=False)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in setp(*args, **kwargs)
    348 @docstring.copy(_setp)
    349 def setp(*args, **kwargs):
--> 350     return _setp(*args, **kwargs)
    351 
    352 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in setp(obj, *args, **kwargs)
   1553         objs = list(cbook.flatten(obj))
   1554 
-> 1555     insp = ArtistInspector(objs[0])
   1556 
   1557     # file has to be popped before checking if kwargs is empty

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have the following versions installed:

NumPy 1.12.0.dev0+cc51ba8

Matplotlib 1.5.2rc2+1938.g4ba20b8

Seaborn 0.7.1

I would really appreciate any insights as to what is happening here. Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me with `numpy 1.10.4`, `matplotlib 1.5.1`, and `seaborn 0.7.0`.

Comment: yeah it used to work for me as well, suddenly stopped and I don't understand why based on the error messages...

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to Matplotlib 1.5.1 and it is working now. Presumably some error in the rc2 version?